# Only Using Angular for Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, knockout.js

I'm working on a single page application and I'm referencing Angular in it. However, the only thing I am using Angular for is the routing (and ng-animate for animating transitions between partials) so that I can change views without reloading the entire page. I don't anticipate using anything else from Angular but I don't know that for sure, as this is my first SPA. I am concerned about things such as load times (especially for international users who aren't near CDNs) as well as security (no point in having potential vulnerabilities if I'm not using those features), etc.

**Q: Is using Angular solely for routing overkill? Should I be using something more lightweight?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJS is a framework use it only for routing it's like use a bazooka for a bug ...

I think you need a lightweight library.

The best choice for routing IMHO it's Sammy.js with mustache.js for templating if you need it.

http://sammyjs.org
http://mustache.github.io

Refer to this post  :
[Comparison between Sammy.js/History.js/Nav.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918770/comparison-between-sammy-js-history-js-nav-js)

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Even Sammy is a bit overkill if all you're doing is routing; Davis.js is a pure router that's intentionally compatible with Sammy. I've personally used page.js, which was written by the author of the Express server-side framework and uses the same router code,as well as being very small; however, it doesn't handle hash-based routing, only pushState (which was fine for my intended use).